# Web 8.5 TtmCdEnvironment creating error

Tags: installation, web8.5

I have installed the Web 8.5 and trying to setup the TTM - specifically the TTM CD environment by running the TtmCdEnvironment command. However, I am getting the below error while trying to run this command in Powershell (opened as an Administrator):

```
Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id LocalCD -EnvironmentPurpose "Staging" -DiscoveryEndpointUrl http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc -AuthenticationType OAuth -ClientId cmuser -ClientSecret CMUserP@ssw0rd
```

**ERROR:**

```
Add-TtmCdEnvironment : Unable to save item of type 'CdEnvironmentData' with id 'LocalCD'.
One or more errors occurred.
An error occurred while communicating with CD Discovery Service 'http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc' in CD
Environment 'LocalCD'.
One or more errors occurred.
The TokenServiceCapability is not configured in the Content Discovery Service http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc.
At line:1 char:1
+ Add-TtmCdEnvironment -Id LocalCD -EnvironmentPurpose "Staging" -Disco ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (Tridion.Topolog...ironmentCommand:AddCdEnvironmentCommand) [Add-TtmCdEnvi
   ronment], DataServiceException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Tridion.TopologyManager.Automation.AddCdEnvironmentCommand
```

I have checked the cd_storage_config.xml for the discovery service and here are how the relevant section looks like:

```
<ConfigRepository CacheEnabled="true" CacheExpirationDuration="600" ClientId="registration" ClientSecret="encrypted:HzfQh9wYwAKShDxCm4DnnBnysAz9PtbDMFXMbPszSVY=" ConnectionTimeout="40000" ServiceMonitorPollDuration="10" ServiceUri="http://localhost:8082/discovery.svc" TokenServiceUrl="http://localhost:8082/token.svc">
        <Roles>
            <Role Name="TokenServiceCapability" Url="http://localhost:8082/token.svc"/>
        </Roles>
    </ConfigRepository>
```

I verified the Discovery service is running and above URLs open in the browser.

It seems I am missing something very common - any pointer would be helpful

Comment: Did you use "--auto-registration" flag when installing or starting discovery-service (to ensure TokenServiceCapability is registered with discovery service)? like for ex: installService.ps1 --auto-register

Comment: I was using quickinstall.ps1 - I think the documentation for installing 8.5 are in its poorest state possible :(

Comment: It is documented as part of discovery registration tool. http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-12D1D919-2D08-40C3-91A0-B6C0A643C29F

Comment: Understood that Vinay; but very difficult to go there while following the documentation thread for the installation - A suggestion to add a comment over there or link to such articles in the installation doc would be really great

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You also need to register the capabilities by doing

```
java -jar discovery-registration.jar update
```

You can also use the tool to check your registrations by doing

```
java -jar discovery-registration.jar read
```

Comment: Thanks Dominic, but where should I find this jar file - I cant see this jar anywhere and getting the error in executing the above commmand:
Unable to access Jar File

Comment: The file is named discovery-registration.jar (note the 'y') and is located in Content Delivery\roles\discovery\registration in the installation folder.

Comment: Thanks Dominic and Peter; this indeed resolved the issue - I wish the documents are updated/created with this information - You guys are awesome
Updated the command as well

Comment: Second that point - massively frustrating to follow documentation that leads you down a dead-end.